# White Screen During Setup. Tried everything

Tags: error, setup

I'm trying to set up Magento locally using **MAMP**, and I'm getting the WSOD.

I've changed permissions, to the point that just about everything has full permissions, and still nothing

I'm running PHP 7.2, and I've been able to run composer install without any issues. When I check the network tab, I see the setup `index.php` come through with a **500 error**.

my `cgi.fix_pathinfo` is set to 1, I have a DB created in PHPMyAdmin with the same name as the root folder, and both the debug log and system log have 2 lines that say:

main.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []

Comment: can you please provide screenshot of error? add magento version in your question.

Comment: The error shows you didn't install the application yet. Isn't it?

Comment: can you please set the permission.